# Svg sprites and svg4everybody

Tags: svg, sprite, svg-sprite

I have a problem with svg sprites. I know how it works and I built plenty of svg sprites, but right now I have no idea what to do. In my project i use svg4everybody.

I have an error in console:

"Unsafe attempt to load URL  from frame with URL . 'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins."

Maybe you know how to fix this bug.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use file urls, run a webserver and load things over http or https.

Comment: Work's fine, thank you! I don't this nuance with http and https